Map from simplex to itself that preserves sub-simplices: revisited
Here it is proved that, if $f$ is a continuous map from an $n$-simplex $\Delta$ to itself, that maps each sub-simplex of $\Delta$ to itself, then $f$ must be onto $\Delta$ (surjective).
I would like to know if the condition can be weakened as follows.
Let $V$ be the set of vertices of $\Delta$. Let $\sigma_U$ be a sub-simplex of $\Delta$ that is spanned by some $U\subsetneq V$.
Suppose $f$ maps each sub-simplex $\sigma_U$ to a set that does not intersect the "complementary" sub-simplex, $\sigma_{V\setminus U}$.
Does it imply that $f$ is surjective?

the link is broken

Let us consider the case $\Delta = [0;1].$ So your condition means that $f(0)\neq 1$ and $f(1)\neq 0.$ That's all, right?

@DmitriiKorshunov fixed

@MaximPrasolov yes

So the map $f \equiv 1/2$ satisfies this condition and is not surjective.
